# Translation Sentence with Four Predicates

Tags: predicate-logic

Not sure if I am to continue asking questions in my old question thread or post a new one since I'm new here so please forgive any perceived spamming on my part.

Given the following predicates and letting the domain for $F$, $G$, and $H$ be all animals.

> $r$: "It is raining"
>
> $F(x)$: "$x$ is a frog"
>
> $G(x)$: "$x$ is green"
>
> $H(x)$: "$x$ hops"

And the sentence `Green frogs hop if and only if it isn't raining.`

Then is my translation correct?
$$[\forall x(G(x)\land F(x)) \to  H(x)] \leftrightarrow \lnot r$$

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Seems okay.  You can write it different, equivalent ways... to me, a more natural translation is $\forall{x} \left(G(x) \wedge F(x)\right) \to \left(H(x) \leftrightarrow \neg r\right)$.

Comment: I can see how that flows better compared to mine. I appreciate the assistance. Thank you!